# I there any way to display the current date as column header in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Wherever I try running SELECT CURDATE(); It's running fine but

on running SELECT CURDATE() AS CURDATE(); it's throwing

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'curdate()' at line 1.

The format I want is

||2020-05-15||
 
 ||2020-05-15||

I am a newbie in MySql is there any way to get the column header as the Current date.

Comment: Parentheses are not allowed in column aliases.  What is the mystery?  Just use `select curdate() as current_date`.

Comment: Well I want the grid header to be the current date as well 
|2020-05-15|
|2020-05-15| Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

// In SQL Server Reference:

```sql
DECLARE @ColumnName AS VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(200)

SET @ColumnName  = CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),106)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),106) AS ' + CHAR(39) + @ColumnName + CHAR(39)

EXEC(@SQL)
```